# Run WPF UI tests during TFS build

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, tfs, gui-testing

For a WPF application I do have custom tests that do instantiate this WPF application within a new thread, then set the viewmodel and test the view directly. This way it is possible to test the actual representation of the view, such as binding issues, rendering problems and the ui controls state.

The tests work fine, when run on a local machine (the GUI pops up and the tests are run). However they don't run correctly during the TFS build, most likely because the instantiated WPF application is not "really" opened/rendered on the server. Basically some ui controls stay empty, I guess because they did not "came into view" on the server.

Do you have any suggestions on how to get this type of tests to work within a TFS 2012 build?

Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 0):

Testing of GUI components on windows is best done using a GUI testing framework such as [CodedUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/dd286681%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I recently watched an [excellent course](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=codedui-test-automation&highlight=marcel-devries_codedui-m2-intro!marcel-devries_codedui-m3-recordandplayback%2a2!marcel-devries_codedui-m4-understandingtheobjectmodel%2a3!marcel-devries_codedui-m5-managingsearchandplayback!marcel-devries_codedui-m7-analyzingplaybackfailures!marcel-devries_codedui-m6-handlingbigprojects!marcel-devries_codedui-m9-datadrivenuitests#codedui-m2-intro) on Pluralsight which goes into detail of how to create unit tests for applications such as yours.